# Parse Query in Swift using query.whereKey

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I plan to retrieve the score of my current user. Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "UserData")

query.whereKey("user", equalTo: "cuWkby3Fm0")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

if error == nil {
    print("successfully retrieved \(objects!.score) ")
} else {
    print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
}
```

The error is

> Value of type '[PFObject]' has no member 'score'

[image: Parse class]

Comment: Please post code, not screenshots of code. Include the error message as text and maybe a screenshot of the message if needed.

Comment: general idea: `objects![0]["score"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`objects` is of type `[PFObject]?` - an optional array of `PFObject`s.

You probably want to get the score of *some* of the contained elements. For example:

```
if let first = objects.first {
    print(first["score"])
}
```

Comment: Yes, and another mistake i made is that I passed a string to the user. Should be an object. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want the score of your current user, then query for PFUser.currentUser() instead of a hard-coded string. Also, make sure you're actually working with a single object instead of multiple objects.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "UserData")

query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
(objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

if error == nil {
    print("successfully retrieved \(objects!.first.score) ")
} else {
    print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all gameScores for specific user. You should **iterate** your data with `for in` loop.

For example.

```
for object in objects {
    print(object["score"])
}
```